# SSIS Package copy/move based on condition. check archive folder before move/copy to process

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm working on a Ssis package and would like to know, how I can achieve the following:

I want to move files from a drop folder into a process folder and I want to implement the following rule:

`If file does not exist in archive move file to process and archive.
If file exists in archive drop file (don't archive and don't move to process).`

The test "if" exists must be based on file name and time stamp (when raw file got created).

Any ideas?

Comment: How about a Script Task?

Comment: @SQuirreL: Did I answer your question.If Yes then mark the answer by tick mark the arrow in the answer. If not please add a comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by simple way which I have done this in few days back.

1) Create a variable `FileName`(string), `FileExists`(boolean)

2) Drag the File System Task and based on your condition you can Copy/Move/Delete file or folder.

3) In my case based on the time frame I archive the file which is move the file from one folder to another by adding one more variable name `DestinationFolder` (string).

4) The condition I applied is in `Precedence Constraint` (right click on properties or double click Precedence constraint editor then expression and constraint and give the expression as `@fileexists` == TRUE or FALSE).

This should work just fine.